# If an invertible matrix $A$ satisfies $c||x|\leq ||Ax|| \leq C||x||$ for all $x$, can one say the same about its inverse?

Tags: matrices, matrix-norms

For every $z$ with norm 1, we have that

$$ 1 = ||z|| = ||AA^{-1}z|| \leq ||A||\cdot ||A^{-1}z|| \leq C||A^{-1}z||$$ and thus, this give us that $||A^{-1}z|| \geq \frac{1}{C}$.

I thought that using the same argument with $A^{-1}A$ would yield the other inequality, but it doens't work... Can one conclude that $||A^{-1}z|| \leq \frac{1}{c}$ somehow? Or if not so, maybe that $||A^{-1}z||$ is lesser than other constant involving $c$ and $C$?

Comment: I added an answer, next time write the question in the body, you have to write the full question in order to be understood without reading the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $c||x||\leq ||Ax|| \leq C||x||$ and $A$ is invertible substituting $x=A^{-1}y$ to the equation we have:

$$c||A^{-1}y||\leq ||y|| \leq C||A^{-1}y||$$
Thus $||y|| \leq C||A^{-1}y||$ and so $\frac{1}{C}||y|| \leq ||A^{-1}y||$ and $c||A^{-1}y||\leq ||y||$ and so $||A^{-1}y||\leq \frac{1}{c}||y||$. Hence:
$$\frac{1}{C}||y||\leq ||A^{-1}y|| \leq \frac{1}{c}||y||$$
as we wanted to prove.

Comment: I see... Somehow I was thinking that you couldn't write $x=A^{-1}y$ without losing generality, but I guess since $A$ is invertible it's ok. Thx

Comment: Yeah, an argument like yours is useful in settings when you don't know whether the matrices are invertible or not. But knowing that the matrix is invertible makes everything much easier.